# Scroll content of a TreeView in PyGObject without scrolling the headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, scroll, pygobject

I want to scroll the **content** of a `Gtk.TreeView`. This means the rows but not the header. So using a `Gtk.ScrolledWindow` will not help here because this would scroll the complete widget.

I found `Gtk.Adjustment` but don't know how to use it.

This is what I tried so far

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class TreeView(Gtk.TreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        # model
        self.model = Gtk.ListStore.new([int])
        for i in range(30):
            self.model.append([i])

        # view
        Gtk.TreeView.__init__(self, self.model)

        col_a = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('int',
                                   Gtk.CellRendererText(),
                                   text=0)
        self.append_column(col_a)

        # "adjustment" ???
        self.adj = Gtk.Adjustment()
        self.set_vadjustment(self.adj)


class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title='Mein Gtk-Fenster')
        self.set_default_size(100, 120)

        self.view = TreeView()

        # layout
        self.layout = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(self.layout)
        self.layout.attach(self.view, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        self.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = Window()
    Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just pack your `TreeView` into a `Gtk.ScrolledWindow`

```
class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title='Mein Gtk-Fenster')
        self.set_default_size(100, 120)

        self.view = TreeView()

        scroll = Gtk.ScrolledWindow () # 1
        scroll.add (self.view)         # 2
        scroll.set_policy (Gtk.PolicyType.NEVER, Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC)

        self.add (scroll)

        self.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()
```

TreeView is smart enough to scroll only contents:

> [image: scrolled treeview example]